# Exibir dados de uma Api em um v-data-table, um objeto dentro de um objeto vue js, vuetify

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, datatable, vuetify

Possuo o seguinte Json vindo de uma api, que quero apresentar em um V-DATA-TABLE:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Ana",
        "lastName": "Lucia",
        "phone": "(11)99989-8989",
        "mobilePhone": "(11)99989-8989",
        "email": "aninha@gmail.com",
        "gender": {
            "name": "feminino"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "inativo"
        },
        "services": [
            {
                "name": "progressiva"
            },
            {
                "name": "Manicure"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Maria",
        "lastName": "Luiza",
        "phone": "(12)32333-3333",
        "mobilePhone": "(43)45555-5555",
        "email": "marialu@gmail.com",
        "gender": {
            "name": "feminino"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "pendente"
        },
        "services": [
            {
                "name": "progressiva"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Mario",
        "lastName": "Braz",
        "phone": "(11)23232-3222",
        "mobilePhone": "(11)23232-3222",
        "email": "mariobraz@gmail.com",
        "gender": {
            "name": "masculino"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "ativo"
        },
        "services": [
            {
                "name": "progressiva"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Porém no Data table o campo que viriam os Serviços, está vindo vazio conforme imagem:
[image: imagem]

Segue o código do data do meu .Vue:

```
data: () => ({
      dialog: false,
      pageTitle: 'Employees',
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'First Name',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'firstName',
        },
        { text: 'Last Name', value: 'lastName' },
        { text: 'Email', value: 'email' },
        { text: 'Phone', value: 'phone' },
        { text: 'Mobile Phone', value: 'mobilePhone' },
        { text: 'Gender', value: 'gender.name' },
        { text: 'Status', value: 'status.name' },
        { text: 'Services', value: 'services.name' },
        { text: 'Actions', value: 'action', sortable: false },
      ],
      search: '',
      employees: [],
      genders: [],
      status: [],
      services:[],
      editedIndex: -1,
      editedItem: {},
      defaultItem: {},
    }),
```

Notei que quando altero esse trecho de código e deixo apenas 'services':

```
{ text: 'Services', value: 'services' },
```

aparece exatamente a quantidade de objetos que são os serviços mas nao os nomes:
[image: imagem]

então suponho o erro esteja ocorrendo nessa parte, alguém poderia me ajudar?

** Atualizado**

Segue método que usei para puxar o objeto principal que é o 'employees' e todos os seus relacionamentos:

```
methods: {
      initialize () {
        axios.get('http://192.168.26.130:3000/employees/').then(response => {
          this.employees = response.data
          console.log(response)
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });
        axios.get('http://192.168.26.130:3000/genders/').then(response => {
          this.genders = response.data
          console.log(response)
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });
        axios.get('http://192.168.26.130:3000/employee-status').then(response => {
          this.status = response.data
          console.log(response)
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });
        axios.get('http://192.168.26.130:3000/services').then(response => {
          this.services = response.data
          console.log(response)
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        });

      },
```

Comment: Status é um objeto enquanto que services é uma array. Esse services vai alguma vez ter mais do que um valor?

Comment: Sim , status a pessoa só terá um, enquanto services ela terá vários, por exemplo manicure, progressiva , e mais outros futuramente.

Comment: Podes mostrar a função/método que passa esses dados do servidor para a tabela? vais ter de fazer um mapeamento aí. Ou no Vue ou no servidor...

Comment: @Sergio acrescentei o código do método na questão, e no caso do mapeamento poderia me orientar como proceder ?

Comment: Ok! os exemplos de json que tens no inicio da pergunta já são uma versão processada desses 4 `axios.get`?

Comment: Se colocares o componente todo posso dar sugestões de optimizações na resposta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você terá que utilizar o slot para formatar o item.

Você pode conferir o exemplo com base no seu código aqui no [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsptstackoverflowcomquestions452043-5dgrr?file=/src/App.vue) e versionei no [Github](https://github.com/rafaelchagasb/answers-stackoverflow/tree/master/pt.stackoverflow.com/vuejs/452043) para consulta futura.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="employees"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
  >
      <template v-slot:item.services="{ item }">
          <span v-for="serviceItem in item.services" :key="serviceItem.name">
            {{ serviceItem.name }}
          </span>
      </template>
  </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Playground from "./components/Playground";
import dados from "./data";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Playground
  },
  data: () => ({
      dialog: false,
      pageTitle: 'Employees',
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'First Name',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'firstName',
        },
        { text: 'Last Name', value: 'lastName' },
        { text: 'Email', value: 'email' },
        { text: 'Phone', value: 'phone' },
        { text: 'Mobile Phone', value: 'mobilePhone' },
        { text: 'Gender', value: 'gender.name' },
        { text: 'Status', value: 'status.name' },
        { text: 'Services', value: 'services' },
        { text: 'Actions', value: 'action', sortable: false },
      ],
      search: '',
      employees: dados,
      genders: [],
      status: [],
      services:[],
      editedIndex: -1,
      editedItem: {},
      defaultItem: {},
    }),
};
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Valeeuuu, muito Obrigado deu certo !!!